# Border Overlapping issue in Latex

Tags: equations, align, border, overlap

I'm trying to create a MATH work sheet in which I need border for every page but when I use \Huge for some eqn (which are really small if I didn' use this code) then the equations overlap on border here is the pic and below is the code.

```
\newpage
\thisfancypage{%
  \setlength{\fboxsep}{4pt}\doublebox}{}
\newgeometry{left=1.5cm,bottom=1cm,top=1cm,right=1cm}
\begin{center}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{enumerate}[label={\arabic*]}]
\setcounter{enumi}{69}
\Huge
\item 
   \begin{tabular}{c}
     $\frac{x}{2}+1=4$
   \end{tabular}
\item 
   \begin{tabular}{c}
     $\frac{x}{3}-2=2$
   \end{tabular}
\item 
   \begin{tabular}{c}
     $\frac{x}{5}+5=7$
   \end{tabular}
\end{enumerate}
\end{multicols}
\end{center}
```

[image]

Please help me by correcting or using some sort of short codes for border.
Thank you

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: What is the purpose of encasing the inline math formulas in one-column `tabular` environments? And why do you encase the `multicols` environment in a `center` environment?

Comment: Please do let us know which document class you employ and which packages need to be loaded in order to get your code to compile.

Comment: One more question: How or where are the macros `\thisfancypage` and `\doublebox` defined?

Comment: please always post examples as a complete small document that shows the problem.